# Number of bounces does not reduce the time of rendering on GPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, blender-internal-render-engine, gpu

I am rendering a complex scene as here http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35337 . I am using GPU GTX 460 on linux machine. I read a lot of tutorial of how to reduce rendering time and noise. I remark that number of bounces in my case does not reduce the time as expected. I am wondering that in my case, I did not use a lot of glossy materials may be!! And an other trick is In the node menu I setup the light as mentioned below. Does it the best way to do? Moreover, I remark that there is some noise even I used samples =100. Any expert of blender help me?

[image]

Comment: That is because your glossy and diffuse bounces are already limited to 4, limiting your max bounces below this number works. And 100 samples are not many if only they are not square samples.

Comment: @Vitaliy As mentioned in the file, I am rendering just one light source. the other 3 light sources are disabled. I did not understand what are you saying "That is because your glossy and diffuse bounces are already limited to 4" I try to put max bounces to 2 or 3 in the light path panel but it did not reduce the time

Comment: Yeah i've just seen it and edited my post but you already answered to it :).

Comment: @Vitaliy, yes I reduced them from the light path panel but it did not make any change about the time rendering as suggested in many tutorials.

Comment: In my case reducing max number to 2 decreases render time for 10 samples from 12sec to 9 and setting max bounces at 0 decreases time to 5 sec

Comment: @Vitaliy, What's your GPU?

Comment: Nvidia GTX 850M